# Ruby on Rails - add fields from a Model on another Model's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, custom-fields

I have two models `Contract` and `Addendum`. Contract `has_many :addendums` and Addendum `belongs_to :contract`

When a new Contract is created, automatically will create a new Addendum but some aditional elements are needed to create the new Addendum. How can I add a field `value`, which is an attribute from Addendum but not from Contract, on the Contract's form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is a **nested form**, which is pretty common in RoR. For more information on nested and complex forms, there's a [section of a Rails Guide for that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms). I'd recommend checking out all of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), which are incredibly helpful when learning the framework.

For your specific question, first tell your `Contract` model to `accept_nested_attributes_for` your `Addendum` model.

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addendum
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addendums
end
```

Next, open up your contract controller, and do two things. One, build an `addendum` when making a new `contract`. Two, allow the nested attributes of `addendums` (assuming you're using rails 4) in your `contract_params` method.

```
class ContractController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    @addendum = @contract.addendums.build
  end

  protected
    def contract_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:field1, :field2, addendums_attributes: [:id, :value, :other_field])
    end
end
```

Last, add the `forms_for` helper in your `contract`s form.

```
<%= form_for @contract do |f| %>

  <!-- contract fields -->

  Addendums:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :addendums do |addendums_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= addendums_form.label :value %>
        <%= addendums_form.text_field :value %>

        <!-- Any other addendum attributes -->

      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

With that, you should be all set! Happy coding!

Comment: c.f. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 or revised version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's working. But, on the Contract's Controller, how can I access the values of the params concerning the Addendum Attributes? Shouldn't it be params[:addendum][:value] ?

Comment: With nested params, simply use `@contract.assign_params(contract_params)` in either your `create` or `update` controller methods to assign the `contract_params`. Then you can simple call `@contract.addendum.first.value` to get your first addendum's value. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Whoops, misprint. It should be `@contract.addendums.first.value`. `addendums` should be plural. Sorry about that.

Comment: So, the Addendum is automatically created? I thought I would have to created later. In fact, on the Contract's Controller `create` I have `if contract.save createAddendum` and createAddendum is a function I've created on the controller which will get the values of the params (concerning the addendum_form) and other fields that are calculated based on other fields...

Comment: Yes, the Addendum is automatically created. You should really take a look at the [first link I posted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) in my answer, as it goes through nested forms step by step, in much more detail than my answer. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to say in your last sentence, but with nested params, you shouldn't need to call a `createAddendum` function if you first `build` an addendum as I do in my answer, and then assign its values using your nested form.

Comment: I asked a new question where I explain the new problem created by the nested_attributes. If you could take a look... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397860/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes-and-automatic-object-creation)