# Ruby on Rails - Nested Attributes and Automatic object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297096/ruby-on-rails-add-fields-from-a-model-on-another-models-form/24297534#24297534) and this one follows...

I have 3 Models: Contract, Addendum and Appointment

```
Contract.rb
  has_many :addendums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addendums

Addendum.rb
  belongs_to :contract
  has_many :appointments

Appointment.rb
  belongs_to :addendum
```

When an Addendum is created, some Appointments are created automatically. I made this work adding a function on the `Addendum's Controller` like this

```
def createNewAppointments
  appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment]);
  appointment.dataprovavel = @addendum.data
  appointment.addendum_id = @addendum.id
  appointment.appointment_state = AppointmentState.where(descricao:'Pendente').first
  appointment.save 
  ...
end
```

This function is called here

```
Addendum Controller
def create
  respond_to do |format|
  if @addendum.save
    format.html { redirect_to @addendum, notice: 'Addendum was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @addendum }
    createNewAppointments
  else
  ...
end
```

Now, because I start using the nested_attributes between Contract and Addendum, the new Addendum is created using the `build` method, so the function `createNewAppointments` is not called... How can I do this?

I tried using `after_create createNewAppointments`, on the model `Addendum` but it doesn't work. It gives an error `Uninitialized constant Contract::Addendum`

Comment: This `Addendum Controller` means `class AddendumsController`?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to move the method from the controller to the contracts model. Models can't access controllers methods.

And replace @addendum with self. Then call it from the controller with:

```
@addendum.createNewAppointments(params[:appointment], 'pendente')
```

Note that you need to pass the params from the controller to the model to make it work.

```
def createNewAppointments(appointment, descricao)
  appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment]);
  appointment.dataprovavel = self.data
  appointment.addendum_id = self.addendum.id
  appointment.appointment_state = AppointmentState.where(descricao: descricao).first
  appointment.save 
  ...
end
```

Your other option is to move the method to the contract controller wich is doing the work right now. As long as the addendums controller seems not to be interacting.

And do something like:

```
@addendum = contract.build....
create_new_appointments
```

HINT: Use rails conventions on naming methods. User lowercase underscores. Don't do JAVA naming.